# want to put inputs of a text file into a multidimensional array and retrieve entries based on array(i,j)

Tags: vba, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

So i have a text file which has a number of lines and each line has entries separated by delimiters.  I have managed to break the data down and put them into a multi-dimensional array, please see code below.

each row has differing amount of entries separated by delimeters

```
Public Sub testarr()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim iFile As Integer
Dim TotalRows() As String
Dim TotalColumns() As String
Dim sData As String
Dim MyArray() As String
Dim fso As Object    

 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  Const forReading = 1
  filepath = "C:\test1"
  Set F = fso.OpenTextFile(filepath, forReading) 'open file for reading

  y = 1
  n = 5 'i've called a function to retrieve num of lines

 'breaking into separate lines 
  For i = 1 To n
  strContents = F.readline
  strconts = strconts & vbCrLf & strContents
    Debug.Print strconts     
  Next

   Debug.Print strconts
   TotalRows() = Split(strconts, vbNewLine)
    'ReDim Preserve TotalRows(y)
  'TotalRows = Split(sData, vbCrLf)
  For y = 1 To 5
  Debug.Print TotalRows(y)
  Next y

'trying to separate each roads by the delimeters
For x = 1 To n
  For y = 1 To 5
 TotalColumns(x) = Split(TotalRows(y), "|")
 Next y
 Next x
```

above splits the rows but each line is the same

```
  For i = LBound(TotalRows) To UBound(TotalRows)
    For j = LBound(TotalColumns) To UBound(TotalColumns)
      MyArray(i, j) = TotalColumns(j)
      Debug.Print MyArray(i, j)
    Next
  Next
  End Sub
```

maybe there is another suggestion to do this.  I just want to be able to retrieve entries of a particular line and column array( line 2, column 3).  But each line will have a different number of entries so i do not want to define the number of columns but will define the number of lines.

Comment: What you want is an array of arrays - split each line to an array and then store each array as an element in the parent array.

Comment: Hi Tim, could you help me start of on this, i don't think i have come across such a concept.  My result just gives me a two dimensional array with the entries being same for each row because the length of the colum length is change on each iteration when i do the split.

so for myarray(0, 0) = 1 i get the same for myarray(1,0) =1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a "jagged" array:

```
'...
TotalRows() = Split(strconts, vbNewLine)

For x = lbound(TotalRows) to unbound(TotalRows)
    TotalRows(x) = Split(TotalRows(x), "|")
Next x
'....
```

Each "row" is now an array, so it would be something like:

```
blah = TotalRows(2)(2)
```

to get the third item on the third row.  Obviously you'd need some bounds checking when accessing each sub-array.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Williams managed to resolve my issue using a jagged array.  I was doing a 2D array and redefining the dimensions therefore when i tried to retrieve it i kept extracting data from the last inputs.

Answer (score 0):

edited after OP's clarification

may this is the code you are after

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub testarr()
    Const forReading = 1

    Dim filepath As String
    filepath = "C:\test1"

    Dim strconts As String
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'create and reference FilSystemObject object
        With .OpenTextFile(filepath, forReading) 'open file for reading and reference it
            'breaking into separate lines
            Do While .AtEndOfStream <> True 'read the file till its last line
                strconts = strconts & .ReadLine & vbCrLf
            Loop
            .Close 'close referenced file
        End With
    End With

    Dim TotalRows As Variant 
    TotalRows = Split(strconts, vbNewLine)

    ReDim TotalColumns(LBound(TotalRows) To UBound(TotalRows)) As Variant 'dim your TotalColumns array with same rows number as TotalRows

    Dim i As Integer, nCols As Long, nColsMax As Long
    For i = LBound(TotalRows) To UBound(TotalRows)
        TotalColumns(i) = Split(TotalRows(i), "|") 'have each TotalColumn element store an array
        nCols = UBound(TotalColumns) - LBound(TotalColumns)
        If nCols > nColsMax Then nColsMax = nCols 'store maximum number of columns across TotalColumns arrays
    Next

    ReDim MyArray(LBound(TotalColumns) To UBound(TotalColumns), 0 To nColsMax) As String 'size MyArray to the same rows number of TotalColumns and the maximum number of columns
    Dim j As Integer
    For i = LBound(TotalColumns) To UBound(TotalColumns)
        For j = LBound(TotalColumns(i)) To UBound(TotalColumns(i))
            MyArray(i, j) = TotalColumns(i)(j)
            Debug.Print MyArray(i, j)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

of course this code can be collapsed further, but that is something you can do afterwards

Comment: actual aim is to put the text file in an array where i can recall a particular entry.  So i can retrieve the entry in line 4 column 5.  But each line does not have the same number of entries.  So line 1 may have 6 entries and 4 with 3.  So I do not want to specify the column dimension of a line but be able to calculate number of entries.

i will see if your suggestion works, thanks.